# How do I set openssl installed via apt as default openssl?

Tags: apt, ssl, versions, openssl, rvm

when I execute :

```
sudo apt install openssl
```

It shows :

```
openssl is already the newest version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7)
```

But querying openssl version via `openssl version` shows :

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022
```

path via `openssl version -d` is shown as :

```
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
```

whereas running `dpkg -L openssl` gives:

```
/.
/etc
/etc/ssl
/etc/ssl/certs
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
/etc/ssl/private
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/c_rehash
/usr/bin/openssl
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/ssl
/usr/lib/ssl/misc
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/tsget.pl
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openssl
/usr/share/doc/openssl/FAQ.md
/usr/share/doc/openssl/HOWTO
/usr/share/doc/openssl/HOWTO/certificates.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/openssl/HOWTO/keys.txt
/usr/share/doc/openssl/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openssl/NEWS.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/openssl/README-ENGINES.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/openssl/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/openssl/README.md.gz
/usr/share/doc/openssl/README.optimization
/usr/share/doc/openssl/fingerprints.txt
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/openssl
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/CA.pl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-asn1parse.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ca.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ciphers.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-cmds.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-cmp.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-cms.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-crl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-crl2pkcs7.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-dgst.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-dhparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-dsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-dsaparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ec.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ecparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-enc.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-engine.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-errstr.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-fipsinstall.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-format-options.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-gendsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-genpkey.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-genrsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-info.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-kdf.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-list.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-mac.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-namedisplay-options.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-nseq.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ocsp.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-passphrase-options.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-passwd.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-pkcs12.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-pkcs7.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-pkcs8.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-pkey.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-pkeyparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-pkeyutl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-prime.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-rand.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-rehash.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-req.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-rsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-rsautl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-s_client.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-s_server.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-s_time.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-sess_id.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-smime.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-speed.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-spkac.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-srp.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-storeutl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-ts.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-verification-options.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-verify.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-version.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl-x509.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/tsget.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man5
/usr/share/man/man5/config.5ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/fips_config.5ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/x509v3_config.5ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_ASYM_CIPHER-SM2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-AES.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-ARIA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-BLOWFISH.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-CAMELLIA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-CAST.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-CHACHA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-DES.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-IDEA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-RC2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-RC4.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-RC5.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-SEED.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_CIPHER-SM4.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-HKDF.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-KB.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-KRB5KDF.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-PBKDF1.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-PBKDF2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-PKCS12KDF.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-SCRYPT.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-SS.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-SSHKDF.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-TLS13_KDF.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-TLS1_PRF.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-X942-ASN1.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-X942-CONCAT.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KDF-X963.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEM-RSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYEXCH-DH.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYEXCH-ECDH.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYEXCH-X25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-BLAKE2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-CMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-GMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-HMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-KMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-Poly1305.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-Siphash.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-BLAKE2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-MD2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-MD4.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-MD5-SHA1.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-MD5.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-MDC2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-RIPEMD160.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-SHA1.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-SHA2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-SHA3.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-SHAKE.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-SM3.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-WHIRLPOOL.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-common.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-DH.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-DSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-EC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-FFC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-HMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-RSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-SM2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-X25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_RAND-CTR-DRBG.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_RAND-HASH-DRBG.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_RAND-HMAC-DRBG.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_RAND-SEED-SRC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_RAND-TEST-RAND.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_RAND.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-DSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-ECDSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-ED25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-HMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-RSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-FIPS.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-base.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-default.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-null.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/RAND.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/RSA-PSS.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/X25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/bio.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/crypto.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/ct.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/des_modes.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/evp.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/fips_module.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/life_cycle-cipher.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/life_cycle-digest.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/life_cycle-kdf.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/life_cycle-mac.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/life_cycle-pkey.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/life_cycle-rand.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/migration_guide.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/openssl-core.h.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/openssl-core_dispatch.h.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/openssl-core_names.h.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/openssl-env.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/openssl-glossary.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/openssl-threads.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/openssl_user_macros.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/ossl_store-file.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/ossl_store.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/passphrase-encoding.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/property.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-asym_cipher.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-base.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-cipher.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-decoder.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-digest.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-encoder.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-kdf.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-kem.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-keyexch.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-keymgmt.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-mac.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-object.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-rand.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-signature.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider-storemgmt.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/provider.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/proxy-certificates.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/ssl.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/x509.7ssl.gz
/usr/lib/ssl/certs
/usr/lib/ssl/misc/tsget
/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
/usr/lib/ssl/private
/usr/share/doc/openssl/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openssl/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/openssl/copyright
/usr/share/man/man1/asn1parse.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/c_rehash.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ca.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ciphers.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/cms.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/crl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/crl2pkcs7.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/dgst.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/dhparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/dsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/dsaparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ec.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ecparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/enc.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/engine.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/errstr.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gendsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/genpkey.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/genrsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/info.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/kdf.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mac.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/nseq.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ocsp.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/passwd.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pkcs12.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pkcs7.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pkcs8.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pkey.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pkeyparam.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pkeyutl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/prime.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rand.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rehash.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/req.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rsa.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/rsautl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/s_client.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/s_server.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/s_time.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/sess_id.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/smime.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/speed.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/spkac.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/srp.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/storeutl.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ts.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/verify.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/version.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/x509.1ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYEXCH-X448.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-CMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-DH.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-DSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-EC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-ED25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-ED448.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-HMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-Poly1305.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-RSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-SM2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-Siphash.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-X25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_KEYMGMT-X448.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-BLAKE2BMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-BLAKE2SMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-KMAC128.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MAC-KMAC256.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_MD-KECCAK-KMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-CMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-DHX.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-ED25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-ED448.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-Poly1305.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-Siphash.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_PKEY-X448.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-CMAC.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-ED448.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-Poly1305.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/EVP_SIGNATURE-Siphash.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/Ed25519.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/Ed448.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/OPENSSL_API_COMPAT.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/RSA.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/SM2.7ssl.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/X448.7ssl.gz
```

**Relevant info**

Ubuntu version : 22.04 LTS

I had installed openssl-1.1.1 using `rvm pkg install` to install a ruby 2.6.x version since it wasn't compatible with newer openssl versions.

Initially after installing ruby, default openssl was still 3.0.2.

What might be the reason for this behaviour and how do i go about solving this problem?

Comment: Please check your [PATH environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). You likely have the system provided openssl in /usr/bin and the rvm provided in /usr/local/bin - and your search PATH has /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich ,  It's fixed now, after changing environment path. 
Please post an answer, so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> path via `openssl version -d` is shown as :
>
> ```
> OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
> ```

The value in `OPENSSLDIR` suggests, that the path for this openssl binary is `/usr/local/bin`. The system version for openssl  is instead in `/usr/bin`:

> whereas running `dpkg -L openssl` gives:
>
> ```
> ...
> /usr/bin/openssl
> ```

Which binary is used when simply called without absolute path depends on the setting on the [environment variable PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Likely you have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your PATH, that's why it uses the rvm installed version instead of the system version.